# Making an overflow scroll for a UL element

Tags: html, css

Recently I learned about the `overflow: auto;` CSS property, and I noticed this worked, but only for when text extended below the given region. I am wondering if there is a similar property to do the same thing, but when there is a UL element inside.

***Overflowing UL:***
[image]

In the above image, you can see the UL overflowing from the designated region.

Any help on how to fix this would be great. I am still a bit new, so if I am saying anything wrong, please help me with that too.

Comment: I believe `overflow` can probably do what you want, but you will need to include a reproducing code example of the problem for us to be able to give any meaningful answers.

Comment: ok ill do that.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of elements take up the space, as long as they're in the normal flow, ie. not positioned other than relative or floated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a region scrollable when it contains a list that extends beyond the region's dimensions using `overflow: scroll`.

```css
.region {
  max-height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  background: blue;
  height: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="region"></div>
<div class="region">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="region"></div>
```